# Will Unity lets users flick the left upper corner to reveal launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open the Unity dash when hitting the top left corner of the screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78522/how-to-open-the-unity-dash-when-hitting-the-top-left-corner-of-the-screen)

Gnome Shell gives uses the option of flicking the left upper corner with the mouse to achieve the same result as clicking ACTIVITIES. Will Unity give users the same option with respect to revealing the launcher? Can users move the mouse to the left upper corner instead of the left edge?

(There is a separate question for [opening the dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78522/how-to-open-the-unity-dash-when-hitting-the-top-left-corner-of-the-screen) with the same action.)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

- Install `xdotool` (a program that allows you to simulate X11 keyboard/mouse input).
- Run `ccsm` (the CompizConfig Settings Manager).
- Activate the *Commands* plugin (probably will crash Unity, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, log in, run `unity --replace`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>).
- In the *Commands* tab, enter the following command:

  `xdotool key super`

  [image]
- In the *Edge Bindings* tab, click on *None* and activate the top-left corner:

  [image]

Now you should be able to open the Dash by moving your mouse to the top-left corner. Works fine here, I just don't know how this will affect fullscreen applications. In the *General Options* plugin options, there's a delay for the edge triggering (*Edge Trigger Delay*), so you can add some delay to prevent accidental activation.