# How to open the Unity dash when hitting the top left corner of the screen?

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz, unity-dash

How to open Ubuntu unity dash when hitting the top-left corner of the screen(i am working on Ubuntu 11.10), Just like in Gnome-shell(i love this feature). using compiz or anything else.

Comment: @fossfreedom I don't see how. OP want's the dash to pop up. The other question is talking about the launcher.

Comment: absolutely correct ...face-palm :)  - +1 on this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install [`xmacro`](http://apt:xmacro).
2. Install [`compizconfig-settings-manager`](http://apt:compizconfig-settings-manager).
3. Open `ccsm` and click the *Commands* button (not the tick in front of it).
   [image: ccsm]
4. Go to the *Commands* tab and copy-paste this line into an empty box: `echo “KeyStrPress Super_L KeyStrRelease Super_L”| xmacroplay -d 1 :0.0 &> /dev/null`.
   [image: ccsm]
5. Go to the *Edge bindings* tab and click the button labeled *None* next to the corresponding command number.
   [image: ccsm]

That should've done the trick.

---

Source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/08/open-unity-dash-compiz-edge-binding-gnome-shell-style/

Comment: @fossfreedom Done.

Comment: Not working with me

Comment: Now working when reading source topic, i install xdotool and write the command xdotool key Super_L instead of the long one